# John 14:14 in P75

Tags: john, textual-criticism

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask, but, I understand that P75 and P66 are the oldest attestations of the word me in John 14:14: "If you ask me for anything in my name, I will do it" NIV

See http://web.ovu.edu/terry/tc/lay10jhn.htm

Nevertheless, i am having a hard time finding online a picture of that page where I can see it. Where would you suggest I can find a picture of John 14:14 from P75?

Thank you.

Comment: Please click [**here**](http://csntm.org/Manuscript/View/GA_P75) and [**here**](http://csntm.org/Manuscript/View/GA_P66), for the respective manuscripts.

Comment: Thank you. On the first link, http://csntm.org/Manuscript/View/GA_P75, do you know what of all the images contains J14:14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to view the relevant "leaf" on P66, please click **[here](http://earlybible.com/manuscripts/p66-Joh-102.html)**. To view the complete transcript of this leaf, please click [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYB1b.png).

In order to view the relevant "leaf" on P75, please click [**here**](http://csntm.org/manuscript/zoomify/GA_P75?image=P75_0019b.jpg&page=2#viewer) and view the large image at the bottom of the page. To view the complete transcript of this leaf, please click [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esubc.png). The brackets in the transcript supply suggested missing information, and letters with dots under them indicate letters that are barely visible in the original.

**Reference:**

Comfort, P.W., & Barrett, D.P. (2001). [*The Text of the Earliest New Testament Greek Manuscripts*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0842352651) (s.n. P66 & P75). Wheaton, IL: Tyndale House, pp. 445-446 and 606-607.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. Two additional questions if you don't mind:
1. What tools did you use, particularly to extract and highlight the transcript?
2. What is the word and meaning, if you know, on P66 (transcript you provided) 5th line from the top, second word, right before 'en' (~ev)?

Comment: @Luis - I use Logos 6 Software. For example, the NA28 does not reference P66 as a source text for the first part of this verse (click [**here**](https://sites.google.com/site/misc282828/1/printscreen.png)), and so the anomalous features of P66 for this verse appear to be the scribe's inattentiveness to detail according to Comfort _et al._ (click [**here**](https://sites.google.com/site/misc282828/2/printscreen2.png)), which is perhaps why the NA28 omits its reference for the main part of the verse, which was not the case for NA26 and NA27.

Comment: And I will continue asking until you get tired (if you don't mind):
1. In conclussion, is there or is ther not, or not conclusively, the word "me" in John 14:14 based on these two documents? To my untrained eye, I see that it the portion where "me" would have been is missing on P75, and P66 shows in that place what seems to be a 'μαι'. Is 'μαι' equivalent to me?

2. I understand Logos comes with many options and add ons. Which type do you have -I definitely need a tool like that, but dont want to pay for more than I can handle.

Thank you.

Comment: @Luis - Please click [**here**](https://sites.google.com/site/misc282828/3/Metzger.png), which is the analysis of this text from various sources. This Logos 6 resource comes from comes from: Metzger, Bruce M., United Bible Societies (1994). _A Textual Commentary on the Greek New Testament_, second edition (companion volume to the United Bible Societies’ _Greek New Testament_, 4th rev. ed.). London; New York: United Bible Societies, p.208. Feel free to ask more questions, however, a new "question" may be appropriate for this site.